# How to display a div outside of multi-leveled menu when hovering on sub-level item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu comprised of HTML and CSS and I'm trying to get it so that once the user hovers over the sub level item within the menu, the div info1 will appear to the right of the menu. Ideally, I would like to do this with HTML and CSS if possible, but if there is a simpler fix with jQuery or JavaScript, that would work too. I would certainly appreciate the help.

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="navigation">
<nav>
    <ul class="top-level">
      <li><a href="#">Top-level Item</a>
            <ul class="sub-level">
                <li><a href="#">Sub-level Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-level Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-level Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Top-level Item</a>
            <ul class="sub-level">
                <li><a href="#">Sub-level Item</a>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-level Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-level Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-level Item</a></li>
                   </ul>
           </li>    
</nav>
</div>

<div ID="info1">
    <center><img src="image.jpg" border="0" height=170 width=250 ></center><br><center><table BORDER=4 CELLPADDING=6 ><tr><td><br>I want this div to display on the right side of the screen once the mouse has hovered over a sub-level menu item.<br><br></td></tr></table></center>
</div>

</body>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
#navigation 
    {
        width: 200px;
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }

#navigation ul 
    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }


#navigation li 
    { 
        list-style: none; 
    }

ul.top-level li 
    {
        border-bottom: #fff solid;
        border-top: #fff solid;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

#navigation a 
    {
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        display:block;
        height:25px;
        line-height: 25px;
        text-indent: 10px;                  
        text-decoration:none;
        width:100%;
    }

#navigation li:hover 
    {
        background: #f90;
        position: relative;
    }

ul.sub-level 
    { 
        display: none; 
    }

li:hover .sub-level 
    {
        background: #999;
        border: #fff solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 200px;
        top: -1px;
    }

ul.sub-level li 
    {
        border: none;
        float:left;
        width:200px;   
    }


#info1
    {
        font-family: "Verdana,Arial,Helvetica";
        size: -1;
        display: none;
    }


*/ I thought this might work*/
li:hover .top-level li:hover .sub-level  +  #info1
    {
        display: block;
    }
```

The code can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/brisket27/C5Pn9/7/

Comment: Don't think it's going to happen with CSS. Simple with JS though (I did it in jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/C5Pn9/8/

Comment: There is not "sibling of my parent" selector in CSS3 (but it will in CSS4)

Comment: Here is a css option you can use but the image or text would appear to the right of the nav not window. http://jsfiddle.net/9nq8J/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not go back or traverse the dom up with CSS. **"There are no parent selectors in CSS, not even in CSS3"** *via [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)*

You can solve your problem with some basic jquery:

## Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/C5Pn9/13/)

```
$('.top-level li .sub-level li').on('mouseover', function() {
    // Position #info1 off to the side of the .sub-level    
    $('#info1').css({ 
        'top': $(this).parent('.sub-level').position().top,
        'left': $(this).parent('.sub-level').position().left + $(this).parent('.sub-level').outerWidth(),
    });

    $('#info1').show();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#info1').hide();
});
```

The current code puts `#info1` next to the sub-level. If you want `#info1` always on the absolute right side of the screen, remove the position code in the js and just apply `right: 0;` to `#info1` in CSS.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject :-D Baaam, there you have your parent selector. Not that this is supported by any browser, but the sole statement "There are no parent selectors in CSS" is wrong, since it's in the CSS Selectors Level 4 Module :-D But that's just a little nit picking, +1 for your answer;)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach was in a correct direction. I'll try to explain why this code did not work -

```
*/ I thought this might work*/
li:hover .top-level li:hover .sub-level  +  #info1 {
     display: block;
}
```

This is [Adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/adjacent), applicable to only the 'Adjacent' siblings.

In your case, div #info1 is outside the nav logic. 
Your CSS rule would work if the div you want to display was placed right after the ul li's

for ex. 
1) In the following example Divs #one and #two are adjacent.

```
<div = "one">I</div>
<div = "two">II</div>
```

but the one mentioned below are not.

```
<div = "cover">
    <div = "one">I</div>
</div>
<div = "two">II</div>
```

2) As mentioned, here

```
 <ul class="sub-level">
      <li><a href="#">Sub-level Item</a>
      </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="test">HERE IS A DIV</div>  <!-- This div is adjacent to ul -->
```

and a CSS rule, will WORK!

```
ul.sub-level:hover + #test {    /* This works because #test and ul.sub-level are adjacent*/
    display: none;
}
```

Said that, I guess it will be easier for you to go for option like jquery to implement your logic instead of CSS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.sub-level li').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#info1').show();
    });

    $('ul.sub-level li').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#info1').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet using jquery for the hover effect:

```
$(".sub-level>li").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#info1").show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $("#info1").hide();
});
```

To display the block on right of the screen you can use either use:

`#info1 {
   position: absolute; right:0;
  }`

or

`#info1 {
   float:right;
  }`